# Apache poi : setting custom properties at worksheet level using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D://New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("newsheet5");
    CTWorksheet ctSheet = sheet.getCTWorksheet();

    CTCustomProperties props = ctSheet.addNewCustomProperties();
    props.addNewCustomPr().setId("APACHE POI");
    props.addNewCustomPr().setName("Tender no = 48");
    props.addNewCustomPr().setId("APACHE POI 2");
    props.addNewCustomPr().setName("tender no = 58");
    ctSheet.setCustomProperties(props);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D://New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
    wb.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
```

Xlsx file is corrupted after writing custom properties at sheet level.

I'm getting an error message as 'excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid . Vefiry that the file has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file' when tried open the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Sheet custom properties only are useable using `VBA`. They are stored in the `Excel` file but the values are within binary document parts `customProperty1.bin`, `customProperty2.bin`, ... This is nothing what `apache poi` provides access to until now.

Using `XSSF` one needs creating the binary document part, then getting the relation Id to that binary document part. Then set `CTCustomProperties` - `CTCustomProperty`. There the Id points to the binary document part containing the value and the name is the property name.

Following complete example shows this. It is tested and works using current `apache poi 4.1.2`. It needs `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` being in class path because default `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar` does not contain all needed low level `CT*`-classes.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class CreateExcelSheetCustomProperties {

 static void setSheetCustomProperty(XSSFSheet sheet, String customPropertyName, String customPropertyValue) throws Exception {

  OPCPackage opcpackage = sheet.getWorkbook().getPackage();
  int i = opcpackage.getUnusedPartIndex("/customProperty#.bin");
  PackagePartName partname = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/customProperty" + i + ".bin");
  PackagePart part = opcpackage.createPart(partname, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.customProperty");
  POIXMLDocumentPart customProperty = new POIXMLDocumentPart(part) {
   @Override
   protected void commit() throws IOException {
    PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
    OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
    try {
     out.write(customPropertyValue.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
     out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
    }; 
   }
  };

  String rId = sheet.addRelation(null, XSSFRelation.CUSTOM_PROPERTIES, customProperty).getRelationship().getId();
  
  CTWorksheet ctSheet = sheet.getCTWorksheet();
  CTCustomProperties props = ctSheet.getCustomProperties();
  if (props == null) props = ctSheet.addNewCustomProperties();
  CTCustomProperty prop = props.addNewCustomPr();
  prop.setId(rId);
  prop.setName(customPropertyName);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

   setSheetCustomProperty(sheet, "APACHE POI", "Tender no = 48");
   setSheetCustomProperty(sheet, "APACHE POI 2", "tender no = 58");

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Axel  Richter ! Im using apache poi -3.17 and poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar and observed the following errors 1. `The method getUnusedPartIndex(String) is undefined for the type OPCPackage` at int i = opcpackage.getUnusedPartIndex("/customProperty#.bin"); and 2. `POIXMLDocumentPart cannot be resolved to a type` at POIXMLDocumentPart customProperty = new POIXMLDocumentPart(part) {      can u help me resolve this

Comment: @h tushar: Well, do using the current `apache poi 4.1.2` version then. I will not changing my code to support an ancient outdated version.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is Very Very Helpful . Can u please let us Know if Writing CustomProperties to a worksheet is possible Using apache poi-3.17 and  ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar.

Comment: @h tushar: Using `apache poi 3.17` you need `import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart`. And since `OPCPackage.getUnusedPartIndex` is undefined, you would need to have a look at the sources of `4.1.2` to get what that method does. Then do reprogramming it for usage with `3.17`. And `apache poi 3.17` needs `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar`.

Comment: Thank you for the Insights !  Let me know if it possible to Write custom properties at sheet level to an .xlsm file using  apache poi 4.1.2 and poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue and found a way to make it work, but it's far from optimal. Here it is anyway and hopefully you or someone else can come up with a better method.

```
package temp.temp;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomProperty;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet;

public class Temp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\myspreadsheet.xlsx");
        try (BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile))) {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); 
            
            for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                XSSFSheet sheet  = wb.getSheetAt(i);
                System.out.println("\nSheetName=" + sheet.getSheetName());
                
                CTWorksheet ctSheet = sheet.getCTWorksheet();
                CTCustomProperties props = ctSheet.getCustomProperties();
                
                if (props != null) {
                    List<CTCustomProperty> propList = props.getCustomPrList();
                    propList.stream().forEach((prop) -> {
                        POIXMLDocumentPart rel = sheet.getRelationById(prop.getId());
                        if (rel != null) {
                            try (InputStream inp  = rel.getPackagePart().getInputStream()) {
                                byte[] inBytes = inp.readAllBytes();
                                // By experimentation, byte array has two bytes per character with least 
                                //  significant in first byte which is UTF-16LE encoding.  Don't know why!
                                String value = new String(inBytes, "UTF-16LE");
                                System.out.println("   " + prop.getName() + "=" + value);
                            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                //Error
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
                
            
            }
            wb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Note that CTWorksheet comes from poi-ooxml-schemas-xx.jar and CustomProperties from ooxml-schemas-yy.jar, so both have to be on the classpath. If you're using modules (as I am), this gives big problems! Good Luck

Comment: Thank you thuan ! Solution that you have shared is to read custom properties at sheet level but not to write custom properties at sheet level. Please do share the same

Comment: @tushar I think answer from Axel Richter-san is enough for you to update. Hope you'll be sucessfull in your life :)

Comment: Thank you ! Axel's answer Helped a lot